# Can a Matlab function be used in a CUDA kernel?

Tags: matlab, cuda, curve-fitting

The `lsqcurvefit` Matlab function is used to fit the paramaters of a model curve to a real curve (acquired data from experiment or observation) so that de square differences are minimized. [lsqcurvefit](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html)

The function is time consuming, and maybe prohibitive if used on large set of curves.

Can it be **straightforwardly** used inside a CUDA kernel, being then all the program coded in Matlab? (Edit: this is, without writing a custom version of `lsqcurvefit` in C for the kernel. For instance: write the kernel code in Matlab (using there "any" matlab function like `lsqcurvefit()`), then compile the kernel with a Matlab provided tool, and finally execute the kernel in the GPU, called from matlab host code).

Thanks

Comment: Your question insn't very clear and seems somewhat contradictory (use a Matlab function within a CUDA kernel and then code all the program in Matlab?). Anyway, you cannot directly use Matlab's functions within a CUDA kernel. But you could write your own CUDA version of a Matlab function and then compile and link it by mex-files to be called by a Matlab script.

Comment: @JackOLantern One of the possibilities (I don't know if valid) could be write the kernel not in C but in matlab (then using there lsqcurvefit). Then compile the matlab-kernel (using a tool by matlab) into the right  CUDA machine-code and then call it from matlab host code.

Comment: I've been using CUDA accelerated functions compiled and linked to Matlab by mex-functions. Currently I'm a Matlab 2010a user and I haven't switched to Matlab 2012 yet. To do what you are saying, you would need a tool compiling a Matlab function to a `__device__` function to be invoked within a CUDA kernel. I'm not aware of any tool doing that. But there are for sure Matlab functions already available for GPU execution within the new Matlab GPU computing capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to [combine the capabilities of matlab with GPUs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/graphics-processing-unit-gpu-computing.html), but there isn't *any* matlab code that can be used in a CUDA kernel.

Comment: Just to be clear, MATLAB has support for `gpuArray` type which allows to perform many array operations on the GPU. It also has a growing list of functions from various toolboxes (Statistics, Image Processing, ..) that have been enabled to work on the GPU. Of course that doesnt mean that you can run MATLAB code in CUDA kernels.. You can though easily call CUDA kernels from MATLAB code: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.gpu.cudakernel.html, or write MEX-files containing CUDA code: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/create-and-run-mex-files-containing-cuda-code.html

Comment: Then, let me see if I understand it right. The kernel *must* be coded in C, not in matlab, so I can't use lsqcurvefit() in a kernel. The only option would be to wait that lsqcurvefit is GPU-enabled in the future.

Comment: I would recommend to read some basic material on the topic of GPU computing by CUDA. One good possibility would be the book by J. Sanders and E. Kandrot "CUDA By Example". After that, you will have a clearer picture and perhaps be able to answer yourself to those questions. Compiling and linking CUDA-based mex-files under Matlab could be tricky if you are doing it for the first time. You can refer to [Compiling CUDA mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/498) for some useful instructions.